# How to use AnkhSVN with an SSH tunnel?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ssh, proxy

For university, I need to tunnel my SVN traffic through SSH because the server is normally not reachable from the outside. I have to work with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and installed AnkhSVN as my VCS.

I now have the problem that I cannot create a tunnel  to the subversion repo. I have done it before with Eclipse with the following settings: I opened putty, connected to myproxy.myuniversity:22. I also created a tunnel with putty under connection -> SSH -> tunnels which forwards the traffic from my local port 5050 to the remote port 22. In Eclipse, I edited the settings for the SOCKS proxy and set it to 127.0.0.1:5050. The fields for http/https proxy were left blank. That worked fine.

But unfortunately, Visual Studio provides no way to edit the proxy settings. In AnkhSVN I can only edit the http/https proxy settings but I cannot change the SOCKS settings which is needed. To change Windows SOCKS proxy does not help either.

Is there any way to tunnel my SVN traffic through SSH or is there any other Visual Studio plugin which supports this kind of proxy? I highly want to avoid to use TortoiseSVN since it has screwed up my laptop ago.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation taken from AnkhSVN wiki:

Source: https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/Faq10#head-5e43a060909fcd04d63e3aeed73012de285b9d90

> You may not have an ssh client available. You can specify the full
>   path to the client in the c:\Documents and
>   Settings\YOURUSERNAME\Application Data\Subversion\config. Make sure
>   you uncomment the # tunnels section and add a line like this:
>
> ssh = c:\Program\ Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\?TortoisePlink.exe
>
> (note the double \ characters and the single \ to escape the space )

**Update:** You'll probably need to use an external application like putty or plink. this link can help you doing it: http://bitworking.org/news/Getting_subversion_svn_ssh____to_work_with_PuTTY keep in mind AnkhSVN is using the same configuration as the svn.exe command line client.

Hope this is what you've looking for..

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I think that's not what I am looking for. The path provided in your answer implies that TortoiseSVN has to be installed. As I mentioned, I do not want to install TortoiseSVN. The plugin works fine without TortoiseSVN; only the tunnel is not working.

Comment: which version of AnkhSVN  are you using?

Comment: Version 2.5.12582.28, i think it's the latest one.

Comment: You probably need to use an external application like putty or plink. this link can help you doing it:
http://bitworking.org/news/Getting_subversion_svn_ssh____to_work_with_PuTTY

keep in mind AnkhSVN is using the same configuration as the svn.exe command line client.

Comment: Putty and plink are available on my system. As mentioned above, it works with eclipse and a SOCKS proxy (http and https proxy settings are empty there). But in the AnkhSVN settings I can only change the http and https proxy but not the SOCKS proxy.

Comment: and for sure , you'll have to change the %APPDATA%\Subversion\config as I marked in my answer above. just the ssh attribute need to point to your PLink or Putty external applications.

Comment: Okay, I specified the path to plink.exe in the file. But it still does not work. Do I still have to change the proxy settings?

Comment: I'm not sure for proxy but Set the following environment variable (by right-clicking on My Computer, Properties, Advanced, Environment Variables, New):-
Variable name: SVN_SSH
Variable value: plink\putty location